# Is it possible to use 2 membership providers in ASP.NET?

Tags: security, authentication, active-directory, membership

I have a website and needs to use the users base from a users database (SQL Server, Oracle, etc) and from a NT user database (computer or domain) for security/authentication of the site.

1. A user logs into the site and enters his/her username and password.
2. The site looks up to the users database (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) if the user exists.
3. If not, the site looks up to the domain (Active Directory) if the user exists.

Is it possible to use SqlMembershipProvider **AND** ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Just add both MembershipProviders to your Web.config and specify a defaultMembershipProvider afaicr

Comment: I mean you can use them both AT THE SAME TIME? If so, how's it going to work?

Comment: It'll check one first, and if that fails, failover to the second one. If you needed to have a unified (some info in ADSI/some in SQL), then you'd probably need to write some custom double access provider